# Verify my proof: if $A \setminus B \cap C = ∅ $ and $x \in A$ and $x \in C$ then $x \in B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

I'm reading Velleman's book "How to Prove it" (3rd edition). Because I'm learning without help from a professional mathematician I need help from the community to verify my proof. The exercise is on page 112, number 4:

> **Theorem.** Suppose that $A \setminus B$ is disjoint from $C$ and $x \in A$. Prove that if $x \in C$ then $x \in B$

**Proof**. Because $A \setminus B$ is disjoint from $C$, $A \setminus B \cap C = \varnothing$. Thus for any $y$, $y \in A \setminus B \land y \notin C$ (1) or $y \notin A \setminus B \land y \in C$ (2). Having the original premise $x \in C$, the second expression (2) must be true, so $x \notin A \setminus B$, which can be rewritten as $x \in A \rightarrow x \in B$ $\blacksquare $

A few remarks here :

1. This exercise does not contain the solution at the end of the book
2. In the proof, I'm using the premise $x \in A$, but it is generated from $x \notin A \setminus B$, and it is not from the original theorem and it is not clear for me why it is needed ?
3. I want the proof to be not too terse and not too wordy, something in the middle

Answer (score 1):

I would do it the following way. Assume that $x\in A$ and $x\in C$, plus $(A-B)\cap C=\varnothing$. You have to prove that $x\in B$, by contradiction you suppose that $x\notin B$. Since $x\in A$, so $x\in A-B$, and $x\in C$. So, $x\in (A-B)\cap C=\varnothing$, i.e. $x\in \varnothing$, we're done.

Comment: Yes, nice proof, very easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Comment about notation: Instead of "$A \setminus B \cap C$" I would write $(A \setminus B) \cap C$. (I'd say that $A \setminus B \cap C$ would be usually interpreted as $A \setminus (B \cap C)$. Similarly as $a-b\cdot c$ means $a-(b\cdot c)$ rather than $(a-b)\cdot c$.)

In your proof you claim that $(A \setminus B) \cap C = \emptyset$ means that for any $y$ one of the following two possibilities is true:

- $y \in A \setminus B \land y \notin C$ (1)
- $y \notin A \setminus B \land y \in C$ (2)

This isn't actually true. It is possible that there are some elements which are neither in $A\setminus B$ nor in $C$. (So the third option is that $y\notin A\setminus B$ and $y\notin C$. We can call it $(3)$, to be consistent with the notation you started using.)

As an example, take intervals on the real line $A=(0,1)$, $B=\emptyset$ and $C=(3,4)$. Clearly, $A\setminus B$ and $C$ are disjoint. But there are many elements such that $y\notin A\setminus B$ and $y\notin C$. For example, this is true for $y=2$.

Of course, in this problem you have the assumption that $x\in C$, which eliminates the possibilities (1) and (3).

Comment: 1) Yes, I agree that union, intersection and difference operations are all equal in the order of  precedence. Actually I use a general rule of evaluating the expression from left to right if there are no parentheses.

2) I don't fully understand your example. What are these $A=(0,1)$ and $C=(3,4)$ sets or "tuples" ? Let say these are sets, then you're saying that $y\notin A\setminus B$ and $y\notin C$, and you say that "this is true for $y=3$", but "$3 \in C$"

Comment: @RobertKadjinskii They were meant to be intervals. I have edited the answer to $y=3$. Concerning, the non-standard precedence of operators, it is better to use what is commonly used (so that you're understood). For example, if by $x+y\cdot z$ you mean $(x+y)\cdot z$, you should not be surprised that other people reading the same text will most likely interpret the same thing differently.